# I need help using CSS and/or HTML to add a picture to the right of the Web Part title

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, html, content-editor-web-part

I have this picture /SiteAssets/CalendarBar.jpg in SharePoint Online that I would like to add to the right of the title in a Web Part.

Can anyone tell me what code I need to put in a Content Editor Web Part in the same Zone to do that?

Here's the code for the Elements for this particular WebPartTitle and titleText:

```
    <span title="Guest Visit Calendar" id="WebPartTitleWPQ8" class="js-
    webpart-titleCell"><h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-webpart-
    titleText"><a accesskey="W" href="/Lists/Guest%20Visit%20Calendar">
    <nobr><span>Guest Visit Calendar</span><span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ8">
    </span></nobr></a></h2></span>

    <h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-webpart-titleText"><a 
    accesskey="W" href="/Lists/Guest%20Visit%20Calendar"><nobr><span>Guest 
    Visit Calendar</span><span id="WebPartCaptionWPQ8"></span></nobr></a>
    </h2>
```

Here's a screenshot.  The picture is currently in a CEWP in the same Zone as the Guest Visit Calendar Web Part.  I want that picture to show up in the gray area to the right of the text "Guest Visit Calendar".

[image]

---

Here's a screenshot.  The picture is currently in a CEWP in the same Zone as the Guest Visit Calendar Web Part.  I want that picture to show up in the gray area to the right of the text "Guest Visit Calendar".
Thanks
[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot or mockup, exactly which place you need to place the image? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img src="/path/to/image.png" style="float: right;">`, `/path/to/image.png` should be replaced with the path to your image.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you manage to get a div/img inside the *.ms-webpart-chrome-title* or *#WebPartWPQ8_ChromeTitle* through coding, I don't think it's possible with CSS alone (or I must have missed something). When trying, I could only get an image in there set as *background-image*, but this is not enough to achieve your goal.

If you succeed this with CSS only, I'd be very curious to know how!